# phonegap ios app map with marker

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I need to show google map in my phonegap App with the marker.

I mentioned my code below.It works well in chrome but fail to work in ios
device.I even cant see the map on device.please suggest me some solution that can work here.
[image]

```
 function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644), mapTypeControl: false
};
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
 mapOptions);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Try this..http://www.kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Tech-Blog/phonegap-cordova-geolocation-integration-with-google-maps-javascript-api-v3.html

Comment: @NijilNair it did not help me